# Multiple External mice show identical issues

Tags: mouse, macos, click

I have a MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021) with an M1 Max chip and 64gb memory. I also use a Logitech G502 Hero as my daily driver. It's been working flawlessly for about a year or two since I purchased it.

A bit of back-story: After multiple long days at my computer, my hand was getting tired. I attempted to utilize an XBOX controller as a mouse, and installed several utilities in the process, as it wasn't as simple as I thought. Here's a list of software I attempted, more or less in order:

- Enjoyable (worked, but was missing some inputs)
- Controller Mate (didn't like, uninstalled immediately)
- Steam (Worked the best, but was clunky as heck to configure.)
- USB Overdrive (didn't try it, uninstalled)
- 11Clicks (MAX/MSP external) (more for diagnosis, this is where I first noticed the click issue.)

Somewhere between Steam and 11Clicks, I began to experience issues. I uninstalled all these using "App Cleaner" from Freemacsoft. (11Clicks was simple to just delete the external.) Over time, I discovered more issues. Here is what I'm currently experiencing.

1. Stuck clicks: If a scroll event is registered while middle click is down, the next click and drag will stick.
2. Horizontal Scroll - Shift + Scroll does not scroll horizontally. It does scroll vertically.
3. Possibly a red herring: tracking has been off. I used to sit at ~3200 dpi. I then had to jack it up to ~6000 dpi, and now I'm at 850 dpi, all of these changes were to achieve roughly the same movement on screen.

What I've done.

1. I've rebooted
2. Uninstall/Reinstall Logitech GHUB.
3. Reboot into safe mode
4. Install LGHUB in safe mode.
5. Tested two additional mice (total of 3 external mice don't work)
6. Internal trackpad has been working flawlessly, though today I've noticed odd scrolling behavior.
7. Fresh install of LGHUB on my old (2012) MBP
8. Tested G502 on 2012 MBP - Worked like a charm, no issues.
9. Reinstalled MacOS 12.6.3
10. Deleted the following preferences:

- com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse.plist
- com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
- com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist

11. Repair all drives and volumes from Recovery OS. (There were some errors, but they were repaired, issue persists)
12. Contacted apple and Logitech support. Both are moving very slow. I will attempt apple again tomorrow.

What I've been unable to do:

I scoured my system folder and deleted a few files related to the software I had installed. I found some .dext files from USBOverdrive and Controller Mate that claim I don't have permission to delete. ("*The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items*").

I've created aliases of all the files that I want to delete or cant, or I suspect might be troublesome.

I want my horizontal scroll back, and I want to be able to use CAD software without fear of my mouse sticking and distracting me again.

Note: I believe this to be one issue, since all issues seemed to show up around the same time.

Any help restoring my mac back to normalcy would be greatly appreciated. I know this is a lot but this is the whole story. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All external mice exhibit stuck middle clicks and no horizontal scroll](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457137/all-external-mice-exhibit-stuck-middle-clicks-and-no-horizontal-scroll)

Comment: Is this the concise question you mentioned in the comments on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457137/all-external-mice-exhibit-stuck-middle-clicks-and-no-horizontal-scroll?

Comment: @nohillside Yes; Allan, no. That is my original question. It's the same issues, but reposted to be more focused, as there were a lot of red herrings in my original post. I'm trying to make it more clear, But it's such a complicated issue that it takes a bit to explain it. I deleted my original question to keep things clear.

Comment: The old question had important details, also in the comments. But fine, let's work from here.

Comment: Anyway, in the current state I would go back to a stable configuration first and to any analysis later. You might want to run the specific uninstallers of the various products you installed (you may have to install them again first), they are most likely more thorough than a generic tool.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: I'm being extremely detailed in what i'm doing and can share the details (It's a lot), but the long story short is that installing and uninstalling had no effect. After uninstalling, USBOverdrive still has some processes running, seen in Activity Monitor. 9 instances of “com.usboverdrive.dext” are currently running.

Comment: Some friendly advice:  start from a known good *base* and work from there.  The current approach is akin to a scatter gun approach; it extremely difficult to follow and creating way too many details to parse through. Start with a mouse you know for certain works the way you expect, the try with your Mac in a clean state (Safe Mode) and go from there.

Comment: Allan, I would have, But I had no idea where to start, and after I discovered that every mouse was affected, there was no way to get to a clean state. The issue was even there in safe mode, as I mentioned, and it wasn't until @nohillside suggested to run the installers that I was able to make process.  All told, the issue is resolved, and we can all finally move on to more important (and probably more fun) things!

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to Apple support today. In about 30 minutes, they had the issue resolved!

USB overdrive installs some driver that apparently was causing the issues. I missed a note about the uninstall process in their documentation: There's a link in the help tab of the application. Clicking that uninstall link, then deleting the app instantly resolved all the issues. My tracking speed went way down, horizontal scroll came back (That made me the happiest) and the stuck click behavior disappeared.

I'm glad they were able to help me. This was really affecting my productivity.